# Is it necessary to use anonymous callback function in onClick handler? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback, onclick

I'm currently learning the react hooks with an online course.

The instructor passed an anonymous callback function onto the onClick handler

```
  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <button className="counter-action decrement" onClick={() => decrementScore()}> - </button>
      <span className="counter-score">{score}</span>
      <button className="counter-action increment" onClick={() => incrementScore()}> + </button>
    </div>
  );
```

But I don't understand why the anonymous callback is needed, and why I can't just pass the function by itself.

Following is what I tried and it worked ok without an error.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [score, setScore] = React.useState(0);

  const incrementScore = () => {
    setScore(prevScore => prevScore + 1);
  }

  const decrementScore = () => {
    setScore(prevScore => prevScore > 0 ? prevScore - 1 : 0);
  }

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <button className="counter-action decrement" onClick={decrementScore}> - </button>
      <span className="counter-score">{score}</span>
      <button className="counter-action increment" onClick={incrementScore}> + </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The additional anonymous callback isn't needed here. Doing it your way is fine.

It *would* be useful to have such an anonymous callback if:

- The function being called was a member of an object, and it needs a `this` context of the object, and the function isn't bound. For example, the following would look pretty suspicious in a class component:

  ```
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  ```

  (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) for many pages on the subject)
- You want to make sure the function is called with a particular argument or arguments, and not with others. For example, you might have

  ```
  <button onClick={() => changeValue(1)}>click1</button>
  <button onClick={() => changeValue(2)}>click 2</button>
  ```

  Or, you might possibly want to omit the [default React event](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) that gets passed as the first argument to an event handler. But, in this case, no arguments are used in `incrementScore` or `decrementScore`, so it doesn't matter.

Additionally, note that you only need to use the callback form of a state setter, eg:

```
setScore(prevScore => prevScore + 1);
```

when the state value that the enclosing function [closes over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) may be stale - if the state setter has been called previously, and the component hasn't re-rendered yet. But for a state that changes only once when a button is clicked, the state value has no chance of being stale. So, if you wanted, in this case, you could simplify

```
const incrementScore = () => {
  setScore(prevScore => prevScore + 1);
}
```

to

```
const incrementScore = () => {
  setScore(score + 1);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see! Is doing it my way ok because it returns another function, not just a value? And also is it still more practical to use anonymous function? Thanks so much for your help 

Comment: Both `() => decrementScore()` and `decrementScore` resolve to functions that, when called, call a state setter as desired. I'd consider an unnecessary wrapping anonymous function a slight anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much  (I also edited the question to anonymous function to be more accurate, thanks to you)

Comment: Oh! And I used prevScore as the score changes based on the previous score, every time the button is clicked.

Comment: The callback is useful only when you've previously called the state setter *before a re-render has occurred*. Since the component is re-rendering every time there's a click, and you're only calling the state setter once when there's a click, feel free to omit the callback form if you wish.

Comment: I finally understood what you explained above after googling the basic terms for 15 mins  a long way to go! Thanks again

Comment: @Suan I was reading about this a few weeks ago :) , this was helpful also:  
 https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates

Comment: I just read the docs and did some of the exercises, and now I have a better understanding of the state updates. I love how they explained things beginner-friendly with examples! Thank you so much x